# How to make one controller the default one when only action specified?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using the standard MVC template from MVC 2013.

There is a `Home` controller with actions About, Contact, etc.

There is an `Account` controller with actions Login, Logout, etc.

The app is deployed at domain `website`. The url http://website will produce the output of /Home/Index, without changing the url in the browser address box, ie what the browser shows is not the result of a Http redirect.

How do I make the url http://website/X route to /Home/X if X is not another controller in my application?  Otherwise it should route to /Home/X/Index.

The reason is that I would like http://website/about, http://website/contact etc without the Home.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414960/hide-one-controller-name-from-mvc-url-show-other-controller-names http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3337372/asp-net-mvc-removing-controller-name-from-url

Comment: Thanks.  It seems that creating a route for every other controller can't be avoided?

Comment: @OldGeezer, It can be avoided using the solution proposed in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A naive solution would be to simply define a new route above the default (catch-all) that looks like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ShortUrlToHomeActions",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home" }
);
```

The problem with this approach is that it will prevent accessing the `Index` (default action) of other controllers (requesting `/Other`, when you have `OtherContoller` with `Index` action would result in 404, requesting `/Other/Index` would work).

A better solution would be to create a `RouteConstraint` that will match our `/{action}` only in case there is no other controller with the same name:

```
public class NoConflictingControllerExists : IRouteConstraint
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> _cache = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        var path = httpContext.Request.Path;

        if (path == "/" || String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            return false;

        if (_cache.ContainsKey(path))
            return _cache[path];

        IController ctrl;

        try
        {
            var ctrlFactory = ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory();
            ctrl = ctrlFactory.CreateController(httpContext.Request.RequestContext, values["action"] as string);
        }
        catch
        {
            _cache.Add(path, true);
            return true;
        }

        var res = ctrl == null;
        _cache.Add(path, res);

        return res;
    }
}
```

Then applying the constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ShortUrlToHomeActions",
    url: "{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home" },
    constraints: new { noConflictingControllerExists = new NoConflictingControllerExists() }
);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.irouteconstraint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. The route constraint thing is too complex and beyond me. No time to understand it to determine whether there are other side effects. First option suits me. For those controllers with a default "document", I can add a route for it before the ShortUrlToHomeActions one.